# Vim auto-completion on substitutions and searches in the command line

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is it possible to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> style auto-completion when doing searches and substitution commands in vim?

What I mean is: say I have a variable named `myNumber` in my current file. If I enter insert mode and type `myNu` and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, it will autocomplete the word to `myNumber` (assuming there are no other words that start with those letters).

Is there any way to get this same functionality on the command line? Is there a setting or plugin that will allow me to type `/myNu` and then hit a key to complete my text search to `/myNumber` ? Or, more realistically: let me type `:s/myN` and complete that to `:s/myNumber` so I can more quickly type out substitution commands?

Comment: Yes, there are at least two plugins for that. Vim.org's script part has a search feature. Use it.

Comment: I tried to search for it there but it was hard to know what keywords to use, so I kept getting results for other kinds of autocomplete plugins. Thanks for being so helpful though!!

Comment: You want something that does "completion" in the "command line" so you search for "command line completion" and you skim through the descriptions until you find a plugin that does what you want (one on the second page and another one on the third page). The whole process shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes.

Comment: @romainl: Maybe it 'shouldn't', but sometimes it does—plugins don't always play nicely with each other. And I think the OP was about whether vim supports this out of the box, an expectation which, IMHO, is quite reasonable... unlike the tone in your comment.

Answer (score 30):

While in command mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> — you will enter command line window. There you can edit your command like in vim. Auto-completion should work too.

Comment: You can also get there from normal mode with `q:`/`q/`

Comment: nice combination of features here!

Comment: @Kevin, `q:` will actually give you command history from normal mode, while `q/` — search history from normal mode (to search forward) and `q?` — search history from normal mode (to search backward). `Ctrl + f` will open command line window with a command history from command mode. So `q:`, `q/` and `Ctrl + f` are not quite the same.

Comment: Why can't I get C-f to work? 

I hit `:%s` then `C-f` but get nothing

Comment: So looks like some sort of config issue. My unconfigured nvim instance processes C-f just fine

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2222 does more or less exactly what I wanted. Upvoting Kent though, because that's really nifty.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin also enables auto-completion in command line.

https://github.com/vim-scripts/sherlock.vim